# Shading areas in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, fillbetween

It's an easy TikZ question for people who use it. I tried reading the TikZ manual p. 112 several times but it seems too complicated on the filling part, all the infinity and whatnot... So I currently have this code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (9.2106,4.228) -- (10.857,0) -- (9.2106,-4.228) -- cycle (9.2106,-4.228) arc (-22.5:22.5:11cm)
    node [left] at (0,0) {$O$}
    node [above] at (9.2106,4.228) {$A$}
    node [below] at (9.2106,-4.228) {$B$}
    node [right] at (10.857,0) {$P$};
    node at (2,1) {0.8 rad};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw (3,0) arc (0:180:3cm);
    \draw (2.5980762,1.5) -- (-2.12132,2.121320)
    node [yshift=-2pt,below] at (0,0) {$O$}
    node [xshift=-2pt,left] at (-3,0) {$A$}
    node [xshift=-2pt,left] at (-2.12132,2.121320) {$B$}
    node [xshift=2pt,right] at (2.5980762,1.5) {$C$}
    node [xshift=2pt,right] at (3,0) {$D$};
    \fill (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] (3,0) circle [radius=2pt] (-3,0) circle [radius=2pt] (-2.12132,2.121320) circle [radius=2pt] (2.5980762,1.5) circle [radius=2pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And what it produces is these 2 pictures, without the shading. I need to shade the areas shaded in this picture and add the 0.8 rad but as you see, the node isn't working for some reason.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly different solution using `intersection segments` (you actually need `pgfplots` for this), and the `tkz-euclide` package for the angle.

Since you mentioned shading, I applied some shading. I had to re-create some paths such as the arc A-B, since it was not "perfect". Basically the arc didn't actually reach the coordinate A:

[image]

So I used the command `<coordinate> to[bend right=20] <coordinate>` which, except for minor (negligible) differences, described the same arc.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}                 
    \draw (0,0) -- (9.2106,4.228) -- (10.857,0) -- (9.2106,-4.228) -- cycle (9.2106,-4.228) to[bend right=20] (9.2106,4.228)
    node [left] at (0,0) {$O$}
    node [above] at (9.2106,4.228) {$A$}
    node [below] at (9.2106,-4.228) {$B$}
    node [right] at (10.857,0) {$P$};
    node at (2,1) {0.8 rad};

\filldraw[draw=black,bottom color=black, top color=white] (9.2106,4.228) -- (10.857,0) -- (9.2106,-4.228) to[bend right=20] (9.2106,4.228);

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (9.2106,4.228);
\coordinate (B) at (9.2106,-4.228);
\tkzFindAngle(B,O,A) 
\tkzMarkAngle[draw=black,size=2.5](B,O,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[dist=1.5](B,O,A){0.8 rad}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[name path=curve] (3,0) arc (0:180:3cm);
    \draw (2.5980762,1.5) -- (-2.12132,2.121320)
    node [yshift=-2pt,below] at (0,0) {$O$}
    node [xshift=-2pt,left] at (-3,0) {$A$}
    node [xshift=-2pt,left] at (-2.12132,2.121320) {$B$}
    node [xshift=2pt,right] at (2.5980762,1.5) {$C$}
    node [xshift=2pt,right] at (3,0) {$D$};

\fill (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] (3,0) circle [radius=2pt] (-3,0) circle [radius=2pt] (-2.12132,2.121320) circle [radius=2pt] (2.5980762,1.5) circle [radius=2pt];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \path[name path=line1] (2.5980762,1.5) -- (-2.13132,2.121320);
    \path[name path=myarc,intersection segments={of=line1 and curve}];
    \filldraw[draw=black,bottom color=black, top color=white]
    [intersection segments={of=line1 and myarc}];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

### Some colour!

Replace the shade colours with `bottom color=blue!50!black, top color=cyan!50`

[image: figure 2]

Comment: Wow that's so pretty. I wonder why the "0.8 rad" works for you but not for me. :S

Comment: @FahimAbdullah This code doesn't work in your document?

Comment: Yeah it works very well. I was jut referring to the node at (2,1) {0.8 rad}; in my code but it seems you made a different piece of code to add the angle rather than this. But why doesn't it work? It's supposed to, since it's a node with some text, right?

Comment: @FahimAbdullah Try `\node[anchor=west] at (.5,0) {0.8 rad};`

Comment: Oh thanks that works (without the \). Although I will stick to your one with the angle marker. It's much prettier. :)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to delimit the areas. For the first case it's easy, but the second one is trickier. In this case the whole semicircle is `filled` but previous `clip` command defines which area will be preserved and which one eliminated.
Both `fill` has been drawn on the `background` layer, this way previously drawn lines appear on top.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (9.2106,4.228) -- (10.857,0) -- (9.2106,-4.228) -- cycle (9.2106,-4.228) arc (-22.5:22.5:11cm)
    node [left] at (0,0) {$O$}
    node [above] at (9.2106,4.228) {$A$}
    node [below] at (9.2106,-4.228) {$B$}
    node [right] at (10.857,0) {$P$};
    node at (2,1) {0.8 rad};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[gray] (9.2106,4.228) arc (22.5:-22.5:11cm) -- (10.857,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \draw (22.5:2.5cm) arc (22.5:-22.5:2.5) node[midway,left] {0.8 rad};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw (3,0) arc (0:180:3cm);
    \draw (2.5980762,1.5) -- (-2.12132,2.121320)
    node [yshift=-2pt,below] at (0,0) {$O$}
    node [xshift=-2pt,left] at (-3,0) {$A$}
    node [xshift=-2pt,left] at (-2.12132,2.121320) {$B$}
    node [xshift=2pt,right] at (2.5980762,1.5) {$C$}
    node [xshift=2pt,right] at (3,0) {$D$};
    \fill (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] (3,0) circle [radius=2pt] (-3,0) circle [radius=2pt] (-2.12132,2.121320) circle [radius=2pt] (2.5980762,1.5) circle [radius=2pt];

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \clip (-2.12132,2.121320) --++(90:2cm) -| (2.5980762,1.5)--cycle;
    \fill[gray] (3,0) arc (0:180:3cm)--cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing about your example that requires `pgfplots`.  You only need `tikz`.  Nevertheless I've kept your preamble.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
        (0,0)           coordinate (O)
        (9.2106,4.228)  coordinate (A)
        (9.2106,-4.228) coordinate (B)
        (10.857,0)      coordinate (P);
    \draw   (O) -- 
            (A) -- 
            (P) -- 
            (B) -- 
            cycle 
            (B) arc (-22.5:22.5:11cm);
    \path
      node [left]  at (O) {$O$}
      node [above] at (A) {$A$}
      node [below] at (B) {$B$}
      node [right] at (P) {$P$};
      node at (2,1) {0.8 rad};

    \fill (B) arc (-22.5:22.5:11cm) -- (P) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path
       coordinate (O) at (0,0)               
       coordinate (A) at (-3,0)                      
       coordinate (B) at (-2.12132,2.121320) 
       coordinate (C) at (2.5980762,1.5)     
       coordinate (D) at (3,0)               ;

    \draw (A) -- (D);
    \draw (D) arc (0:180:3cm);
    \draw (C) -- (B);
    \fill (O) circle [radius=2pt] node [yshift=-2pt,below] {$O$}
          (D) circle [radius=2pt] node [xshift=2pt,right]  {$D$}
          (A) circle [radius=2pt] node [xshift=-2pt,left]  {$A$}
          (B) circle [radius=2pt] node [xshift=-2pt,left]  {$B$}
          (C) circle [radius=2pt] node [xshift=2pt,right]  {$C$}
          ;
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}
                              {\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}
    \edef\aeAngOC{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}
                              {\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
    \edef\aeAngOB{\pgfmathresult}

    \fill (B) -- (C) arc (\aeAngOC:\aeAngOB:3cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To facilitate things, I've named the coordinates.

The first picture is easy enough to create and I'll leave my code for it unexplained.

For the second picture a bit more work needs to be done.  I need just the portion of the arc above the chord.  To create only that portion of the arc, I find the angles along `OC` and `OB`.  This is done with the command:

```
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{<point>}{<point>}
```

But `pgf` does not expect coordinate or node names, to get around this I use the macro

```
\pgfpointanchor{<coordinate name>}{center}
```

`\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` doesn't return a value; it saves the calculated angle to `\pgfmathresult`.  I need to save this value before I do anything else with TikZ.  (TikZ uses this macro all over the place in many, many of its path calculations etc.)  To extract the value of `\pgfmathresult` I use

```
\edef<command sequence>{\pgfmathresult}
```

Using `\edef` here is important because you want the value of `\pgfmathresult` at the time of the definition.

Comment: Thanks so much. I used pgfplot so it loads anything else I might need from TikZ like the library stuff and all. Ofcourse I could load only TikZ and then anything else separately but I guess this is more compact.